# Emulating an HTC device for development

Tags: android, android-emulator, hardware, htc-android

I developed an app that works perfectly on all devices I've tested it on so far, including two emulators, a Motorola, and 2 different Samsung phones, but when running on an HTC m8 `HTTPGet` doesn't work, the app doesn't crash, it just hangs indefinitely. The problem is, I don't have access to this physical device, is there a way to emulate this specific device? Alternately, is there a way to emulate a kind of generic HTC device?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  THe problem is it isn't just the hardware, you'd need the exact version of the OS they use, which may have (probably does with HTC) proprietary changes to the OS.  Without knowing what those are we can't emulate them.